# How can I retrieve data from Google Cloud Storage into the SQL Server

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to retrieve data from Google Cloud Storage without third party apps?

I tried with python but I'm getting error code below.

```
import json

from httplib2 import Http

from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

from apiclient.discovery import build

# Change these variables to fit your case

client_email = *******.iam.gserviceaccount.com

json_file = C:\******

cloud_storage_bucket = pubsite_prod_rev_********

report_to_download = installs_********_201901_app_version


private_key = json.loads(open(json_file).read())[my private key here]

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(*******@gmail.com,my_private_key here),

storage = build('storage', 'v1', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))

print storage.objects().get()

   bucket=cloud_storage_bucket

   object=report_to_download).execute()
```

Python throws this error:

> multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message comes from your incorrect Python format, syntax or indentation.

Look at the last statement you want to execute, the `bucket` and `object` should be inside the get().

```
print storage.objects().get(
    bucket=cloud_storage_bucket,
    object=report_to_download).execute()
```